# RadioGroup checked selected value in short way ext.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

aspx.cs

```
string aa= dt.Rows[0]["fruit"].ToString();
  if (aa== "apple")
    {
      RadioApple.Checked = true;
      RadioLemon.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
      RadioLemon.Checked = true;
      RadioApple.Checked = false;
    }
```

I would like to make it in short way like this:

```
string aa= dt.Rows[0]["fruit"].ToString();
   RadioButton rb= RadioGroupFruit.Items.Find(aa);
   rb.Checked = true;
```

Any ideas?
using ext.net in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

For RadioButtonGroups & CheckBoxGroups try getting the value of the BoxLabel.

```
// pseudo code
string[] selectedFruit = this.CheckboxGroupFruity.items.where(q => q.Checked).select(q => q.BoxLabel).ToArray();
```